# How to use Xrray methods without writing to memory

Tags: memory, computer-science, dask, ram, python-xarray

I am struggling to complete a task, whereby we we do a lookup of values from an Xarray.Dataarray to two Xarray.Datasets WH and RHO_L which are created from the subset.

WH and RHO_L have dimensions Time: 8653, south_north=432, west_east=653.

da is an Xarray which has wind speed and air density, in a table format. The columns are your air densities and row your wind speed. For each wind speed and air density there is a power value. Its a look up table.

Example, where wind speed is 5m/s and air density is 1.125 the power is 2500.

We need to perform this operation for every time step in our subset.

Below is the code

```
        subset= ds.sel(Time='1990-01','1990-06')
        ws = np.sqrt(np.square(subset.U) + np.square(subset.V))
        WH = np.ceil(ws * 2) / 2
        WL = np.floor(ws * 2) / 2
        Rho_H = (np.ceil(subset.RHO * 40) / 40)
        Rho_L = (np.floor(subset.RHO * 40) / 40)
        
        WH= WH.where(WH > 3.0, 0)
        WH= WH.where(WH<24.5,24.5)
        
        WL= WL.where(WL > 3, 0)
        WL= WL.where(WL<24.5,24.5)

        Rho_L= Rho_L.where(Rho_L > 0.95, 0.95)
        Rho_L= Rho_L.where(Rho_L< 1.275, 1.275)
        
        Rho_L=Rho_L.astype(str)

        # Assuming da is already defined and it's a lookup table
        power=da.sel(row=WH, column=Rho_L)
        power = (power / 2)
        power.name = 'Power_Curve'
        power_curve_dataset = power.to_dataset()
```

What is computationally expensive is power=da.sel(row=WH, column=Rho_L) and is eating up all on my 400G RAM.

Can someone assist with a way that does the power mapping without having to write the WH and RHO_L into memory?

Thank you